# How to handle multiple response MIMETypes with Restkit 0.20

Tags: ios, mime-types, restkit-0.20

I have an iOS app using Restkit.  Most of the response bodies from the server are in XML format.  However, there is a few API's that will only send a response like "Success" in text/plain format.  When calling these API's I get a 200 response but restkit will throw a mapping error because it is expecting `Content-Type = application/xml` as is seen in the error below.

```
NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/xml'} response.body=success
```

I am using the `RKXMLReaderSerialization` class to interpret the XML received from the server and this is how I register it.

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/xml"];
```

It appears from the documentation you can register multiple MIMETypes but I haven't been able to figure out how.  If that is possible can someone point it out to me.  If not is there a way to handle this?

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**

After further research and help from Wain I discovered the error above was actually stating that the `response-header` for `content-type` had a value of `application/xml`.  This keyed restkit to try and map the `response.body` as an `application/xml` formatted body.  With a `response.body` containing only the word "success" the response was unprocessable.  I ended up pointing this out to my server guy and he corrected the response to be formatted in the MIMEType declared by the `Accept` header sent with the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:` on your `RKObjectManager` to tell it what mime types are acceptable in the response. You may need to define and register your own serialisation class too so that RestKit can execute the whole mapping workflow without errors.

Comment: Thanks Wain, I know that I currently utilize `setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:`. I failed to investigate it last night because I assumed it was used to set the "Accept" header for the request. I will look into it this evening. By chance do you know how to set more than one? I.E. something like this `setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType: someMIMEType, someOtherMIMEType` or does it require `setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType: someMIMEType` new line of code `setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType: someOtherMIMEType`?

Comment: It is used for the request accept header : I.e. for this request, what response types can I accept. I believe it's additive so each time you call it the response type is added to the list of acceptable options.

Comment: In that case I may need to talk with my server guy.  I am already sending the accept header as application/xml.  I will continue to research this tonight

Comment: All RestKit wants is for the server to respond with a format that your code says is acceptable. Anything else will generate the error you see.

Comment: Spot on as usual Wain! Your last comment is what helped clue me into the "true" problem I was facing.  It wasn't that I needed to register another `MIMEType` it was that the response header from the server declared the content-type to be `application/xml` when it was actually `text/plain`.  I pointed this out to my server guy and he altered the response to be formatted in the `content-type` declared by the Accept header.